# How can I send and receive data to a fingerprint device using Java

Tags: java

How can I send and receive data to a **fingerprint device** using **java** ,

I am working on a desktop application using `java` that controls the fingerprint device and I need at some point to send and receive data from and to the fingerprint device.

My question is how to connect the **device** to the **desktop application** and how to send and receive data.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: alright sir , thank you for the help

Comment: Simple answer will be "it depends..." try to narrow it down some more, what kind of fps are you using, how do you plan to connected it? What frameworks are you planing to use. Are you looking for the captured image or do you want to use the authentication system already in place.

Comment: Actually I don't know what framework to use , basiclly the fingerprint device has an Access DataBase where it stores time of entery and time of exit and who's fingerprint is this one , and my java application need to get those information from the database to do statistics, please help